# JQuery - $(this).attr('name')

Tags: jquery

I have a `name` attribute assigned to a hyperlink.
When I do the following with jQuery `link_name` does not return anything.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
$("body").delegate("a", "click", function (event) {

    var link_name = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(link_name);
```

Comment: In cases like this, it is useful to check what you are actually getting: put `console.log(this)` inside the handler (same idea as `alert`, but much more friendly). Make sure you are using a browser that gives you easy access to the developer console.

Comment: There must be something else going on that you haven't disclosed because your code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fqM2V/.  Are you waiting for the document to load before this code runs?

Comment: Something is strange about your code -- usually an anchor tag has *either* an `href` attribute (is clickable) *or* a `name` attribute (is not clickable), but not both. Perhaps you should be setting `var link_name = $(this).attr('href')` instead?

Comment: Did you leave off the closing `});` from your code above that I have in my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fqM2V/?  Is your error console showing any errors?

Comment: This seems to work for me. Can you provide an example of it not working in JSFiddle??

Comment: Come on Nate.  You post a question, get a bunch of questions in return and you're not around to clarify things?  That's not an effective way for anyone to use SO.  When you ask a question, you should check back several times in the next 30-60 mins to see how it's going and if your question is clear or there are issues with it.  You're not a SO newbie so you should know this.

Comment: Comment on closing: This question is not clear enough to be answered, but it hasn't gotten an explanatory comment or edit in a year. Whatever the question was, it is likely to have been lost or forgotten.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd use this (using newest jQuery):

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    var link_name = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(link_name);
});
```

Comment: -1 Downvote because it doesn't explain anything about why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: With that much code (including missing ending brackets etc), its' not clear at all what the error is. By dropping in this code where his is he should be able to see the obvious error. This will give him confidence in this section of code, and hopefully allow him to see the real error.

Answer (score 2):

**Quote OP:**

> Am I doing something wrong?

As noted by others, your code should work if you add the missing closing brackets. `});`

You also did not state which version of jQuery, however, using the latest version of 1.7, you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)<sup>1</sup> instead of `delegate()` and [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`.

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    var link_name = $(this).prop('name');
    alert(link_name);
});
```

> 1. As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: that's kind of irrelevant though, because the code provided actually works.

Comment: Downvote for note answering the question.  The OP asked about .delegate().

Comment: @fritzfromlondon, even if it's currently working _for you_, we don't know exactly what else the OP is doing here to break it.  Since both methods have been updated, the OP should take notice.

Comment: @Sparky672 that is not an answer

Comment: @jfriend00, **Where exactly does the OP ask about `delegate`?**  See title: "JQuery - $(this).**attr**('name')" and the OP says, _"my JQuery link_name does not return anything."

Comment: They're asking why their code (which uses `.delegate()`) doesn't work.  That's the question.  Moving away from `.delegate()` has nothing to do with their particular problem as `.delegate()` works just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00, This is the exact question, _"Am I doing something wrong?"_  I'd say using methods superseded by newer methods is _something wrong_... along with leaving off the brackets as others have noticed.

Comment: The OP doesn't say anything about using jQuery 1.7+ so you have no reason to "know" that `.delegate()` is no longer recommended and even if it isn't recommended, it still works in 1.7+ and will for a long time so that has nothing to do with why their code doesn't work (as shown in the jsFiddle I posted in a comment to their question).  In fact, in versions of jQuery prior to jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` is specifically recommended over `.live()`.  The fact is - changing to `.on()` or `.prop()` has nothing to do with fixing their problem.